# AggregateCursor PHP to MongoDB on hosting

Tags: php, mongodb, hosting

I am trying to use function `aggregateCursor` in my PHP page to take data from my MongoDB.

This is my query:

```
db.wisata.aggregate([
    {"$match": {
        "jenis": { 
            "$exists": true,
            "$ne": null 
        }
    }},
    {"$group": {_id:"$jenis"}}
])
```

This is my PHP code :

```
$collection = $koneksi->wisata;

$math = ['$match'=>['jenis'=>['$exists'=> 'true', '$ne'=> 'null']] ];
$group = ['_id'=>'$jenis'];
$cari = [$math,['$group'=>$group]];

$cursor = $collection->aggregateCursor($cari);
$response = array(); 
foreach ($cursor as $obj)
{   
    $jenis = $obj['_id'];       
    array_push($response,array
    (   "jenis"=>$jenis )); 
}
echo json_encode(array('data'=>$response));
```

I can show my data with database and PHP server on my localhost (on my computer), and when I try my query to mongoshell on my hosting the result is right, but when I try to upload my database and my PHP file to hosting and show with PHP, the page gives me an error.. I don't know where the code is wrong code.

Comment: and if i use funstion agregate and show data with  var_dump($cursor);
result is right like result with mongoshell i think i have error with agregateCursor

Comment: What error is thrown?

Comment: just error like this :

Page satasia.web.id not work
satasia.web.id currently unable to handle the request.

Comment: Please check your webserver's logs for concrete error

Comment: I've found a way.
finally I use agregate function and then call with two foreach. I still do not know why agregateCursor function can not be executed while in servicing my computer still can.
but thankyou for the response @malarzm